# Corralling multiple drain hoses

Tags: drain, sink, utilities

I'm trying to get my utility room in order, and one issue I'm finding is drain hoses.

- My washer has a drain hose that drains in to the utility sink.
- My water heater has the T&P drain that currently sits over bare floor, which might someday cause hot water to fill up my utility room.
- My humidifier has a drain hose that drains to the floor drain
- My dehumidifier has a drain hose that drains to the floor drain
- My furnace has **two** drain hoses that drain to the floor drain
- My water softener has **two** drain hoses that drain the the utility sink

That's eight drains, with varying requirements for air gaps, maximum heights, end heights, run lengths, etc. What I would like is to get as many hoses as possible off the floor, and ideally I'd like them all to drain to the utility sink because our floor drain is sketchy as hell. I'm not entirely against adding additional plumbing if that would help, but running adequate vents from the utility room is a pain.

Any suggestions, products, alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it condensate pump or multiple condensate pumps to handle all the drain lines and pump them into a laundry tub or another suitable location. It's one more link in the chain that can fail and you have to check the capabilities of any condensate pumps that you are using in regards to flow rate and holding capacity. Your T&P valve should be pipes to the floor within 6 inches of the floor and not pipes to a drain or condensate pump the idea being if there is a drip or a leak from there it gets noticed and repaired. Water softeners will all often flow more than what they condensate pump is capable of handling. A higher flow pump I'm sure is available.

**Condensate pump**
[image]
[Amazon](https://www.amazon.ca/Little-Giant-553206-Automatic-Condensate/dp/B000PH2IO4/ref=asc_df_B000PH2IO4/?tag=googleshopc0c-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=292939035572&hvpos=1o3&hvnetw=g&hvrand=12095685665691140177&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9000850&hvtargid=pla-404028756927&psc=1#)

This one looks like a pretty heavy duty condensate pump. For a hundred and fifty bucks with a 4.5 gallon per minute rating seems like a pretty good deal it might be up to the task. Not for the washer though. They can dump like 15 gallons per minute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what local code may say about all this but depending on the proximity of things to each other one idea is to attach all the hoses, etc. to a single 2" pvc pipe and have it run to the floor drain. Doesn't get it to the sink but does concentrate everything to a single pipe. You could even go as far as having the pvc pipe run to a pump of some kind, similar to sump pump, that would kick on and pump the water to the sink.